# How to use Recycler view in Horizenatl Scrolling

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

i have a design which have a linear layout and 1 Recycler view.The linear layout contains a table row having fields names as : Course ID, Course Title, Credit Hour, Status and Recycler view is to display rows data. i want to set Horizental scrolling that scroll both Recycler view and other design of main xml file. Here is my main XML file names content_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    tools:context="com.example.soulshunter.revandhv.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Registered Courses"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="24sp">

        </TextView>

    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#EEE"
        android:padding="16dp" />

    <TableRow

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#00CC99">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Class"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp">

        </TextView>

    </TableRow>

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TableRow

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ccffff">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="102dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Course Code"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp">

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Course Title"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp">

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Credit Hours"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp">

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Status"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp">

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Action"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp">

            </TextView>

        </TableRow>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and i had also tried this in my java file

```
mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(crList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set horizontal scroll as the parent in ur layout. And for recycler view u can set the scroll properties in ur recycler view layout manager.